# Get values from xml dynamically

Tags: android, xml, string

i have this question about get string values without use an string-array on xml, i just don't know if its possible.

My file.xml can have both this

```
<resources>
   <string name="test1"></string>
   <string name="test2"></string>
</resources>
```

and this:

```
<resources>
   <string name="test1"></string>
</resources>
```

Is there any way to get the values programatically, without an array.

The problem is, i can't do this:

```
R.string.test1; 
R.string.test2;
```

Because not always i have the "test2" string. Is there any way to get all the values dinamically?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you not always have a test2 string?

Comment: You need to explain more.  Where are you storing these 2 different files since they can't be in the same directory?

Comment: It's a customization. One time i could have only test1, or test1, test2 and test3, or 10 values. U know? It's dynamic.

Comment: Yeh, very funny.  I assumed that you were using resources XML in /res/values since you did not state otherwise, hence the question.

Comment: Yeah, but i am. It's a customization of the resource.xml :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could receive the string with its name (instead of its id):

```
   String packageName = getPackageName();
   int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("test2", "string", packageName);
   String test2 =getString(resId);
```

Comment: works perfectly =) I just added a try/catch to continue the loop when doesn't exist a string and vualá! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String test1 = getResources().getString(R.string.test1);
String test2 = getResources().getString(R.string.test2);
```

[more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html#stringresources)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, then it is the whole point that R.string.test2 isn't available.